# "export default myFn" vs "export { myFn as default }"

Tags: javascript

```
const myFn = () => {
  console.log('hello world');
}
```

Is there any benefits on using below export methods one over the another?

```
export default myFn
```

vs

```
export { myFn as default }
```

I tried compiling it in babel, I got this results:

```
// export { myFn as default }
// this throws error if function not found
// /repl: Export 'myFn' is not defined
exports.default = myFn;

// export default myFn // this doesn't error like mentioned above 
var _default = myFn;
exports.default = _default;
```

There seems no benefit other than save a line of code `var _default = myFn;` :) , is that correct?

Comment: Both are same. No difference in using  export default myFn and export { myFn as default }.

Comment: I dont see a benefit both are ES6 default modules

Answer (score 0):

They are same. 
I write these two statements into two typescript file. Then compile them into javascript. No matter to what version of javascript, there is no difference between the two result js file.